# Tomcat Start up error in Restful web service using Jersey

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I got tomcat startup exception this

```
SEVERE: Servlet /WebServiceModule threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

After getting exception tomcat startup and work fine but it doesn't work as expected.

I have included the following jersey and its dependency in the java build path

```
jersey-bundle-1.17
jaxb-imp-2.2.4
jaxb-api-2.2.9
asm-3.1
```

In jersey bundle library com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet package exists and it have ServletContainer.class file. I am using tomcat 7.0 server and all of the work is doing in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer” is included in “jersey-server.jar“. Make sure you have it in your dependency path. If you are using maven then use this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: i have included jersey bundle. Is it didn't include all of the jersey-server-api, client and core api??

Comment: thanks. jersey-server.jar files is necessary. May be tomcat search serveletcontainer in jersey-server-jar file not the jersey-bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Which building tool do you use ? Maven ? Build by means of IDE ?  Make sure that all libraries are deploayed with/inside your War ! Everytime I got this exception, adding the missing library into War file solved the problem.

If you build with your IDE, you most certainly need to tell it first which packages will be included in your deployed WAR.

Answer (score 0):

The `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` is included in `jersey-server.jar`, not `jersey-core.jar`. To develop REST service with Jersey, you just need to include `jersey-server.jar`, and it will download the `jersey-core.jar` dependency automatically. Only add the dependency in pom.xml as shown below:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
   <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Now your application will have the class `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`